# Flag reason stuck as selected when trying to flag a comment too quickly

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Flag a comment.
2. Flag a second comment quickly enough to get the error message (within 5 seconds?).
3. Observe the error alert.
4. Observe that the reason for flagging is still selected, but I cannot re-submit the flag (flag button is disabled).

Expected behavior:
The cell of the previously selected flag reason should either be unselected, or the flag button enable for the previously selected flag reason.

It's probably just a case of changing the `UITableViewCell` state or calling `selectRowAtIndexPath:`.

> [image: Flag Reasons]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)

Comment: Just... don't be so quick? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6.1.

We're already putting a modal overlay above the view controller that blocks taps.  No reason to also disable the button.